# jquery combobox change: function( event, ui )

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In jquery combobox change event, how can I get hold of the control which fired this event?

I can see the changed text from $(this).val();, but no information regarding which combox is changed.

None of the below works:
$(this).attr('id');

Comment: Please add some demo source.. May be a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The callback is provided with an `event` argument.

To get the source, use [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)